# How to save raster data from a remote ArcGIS Image Server to my local geodatabase using ArcPy?

Tags: raster, arcpy

First I need to save the raster data from

https://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/fveg/ImageServer

to my local geodatabase. This raster data is associated with a raster attribute table. I tried to use arcpy.management.CopyRaster but failed:

```
arcpy.management.CopyRaster("https://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/fveg/ImageServer", "fveg.tif")
```

Also I need to polygonize this raster data based on the field "WHR13NAME" after saving it. Note that "WHR13NAME" is included in the raster attribute table.

How to save this raster data with the raster attribute table by using ArcPy?